# Bootstrap breadcrumb vertical center

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I think it maybe is stupid question.
I would like to set bootstrap breadcrumb vertical center in breadcrumbs box, but somehow this breadcrumb goes box's top.
Anyone can help it?
Here's an inline link to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bbnf2f0L/).

css:

```
.breadcrumbs{
    height: 100px;
    border:3px solid
}
```

html:

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <ul class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Library</a></li>
            <li class="active">Data</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this css

```
.breadcrumbs{
    height: 100px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
}
```

If this is not what you want then please post/attach a image that how would you like to see the breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 8):

```
<ol class="breadcrumb justify-content-center">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Library</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Data</li>
</ol>
```

This one helps

Answer (score 0):

To work with **Bootstrap 4** and not stick to `line-height` property you can use `.align-items-center` class.

```
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
  <ol class="breadcrumb align-items-center">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Library</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Data</li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/SandroMiguel/s7ot2um0/

Bootstrap Breadcrumb: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/breadcrumb/